# How to associate a USB headsets microphone and earphone/speaker

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, microphone, headset

**Background**

I need to display a list of connected headsets (combined microphone and earphone) in a softphone application. For testing I have the following devices:

- Jabra PRO 9470
- Plantronics BT300M
- Logitech G430 Gaming Headset

The user should be able to select a headset from a `ComboBox`, without selecting the microphone and earphone separately.

**The information**

I know where to find the information (in Windows) about the microphone and earphone, but I have not been able to get it using `WMI` or `MMDevice API`.

To find the information, right click on `Sound` (Speaker icon) in the right side of the taskbar and select `Playback devices`.

[image: Headset properties]

1. Open the properties window by double clicking or click on `Properties`.
2. Click the `Properties` button on the properties window.
3. Click the `Details` tab and find the `Children` property in the `ComboBox`.

This will give me the following information:

```
SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.0.00000000}.{f2e09e37-8389-46c4-8b2b-53e08b874399}
SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.1.00000000}.{3402ee6e-d862-47ca-8ab8-bb8254216032}
```

The first line matches my `Headset Earphone (Jabra PRO 9470)` and the second `Headset Microphone (Jabra PRO 9470)`.

To get the same information in C#, I'm loop through the [Win32_USBControllerDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class and outputting all values containing "MMDEVAPI". On my PC it will return 6 values (3 x microphones, 3 x earphones).

```
foreach (var device in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice").Get())
{
    foreach (var property in device.Properties)
    {
        // Gets the value of the property on the device.
        var value = property.Value == null ? string.Empty : property.Value.ToString();

        if (value.IndexOf("mmdevapi", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
        {
            // Output connected USB microphones and earphones.
            Console.WriteLine(property.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, the above code will output:

```
\\PC9018\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="SWD\\MMDEVAPI\\{0.0.0.00000000}.{F2E09E37-8389-46C4-8B2B-53E08B874399}"
\\PC9018\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="SWD\\MMDEVAPI\\{0.0.1.00000000}.{3402EE6E-D862-47CA-8AB8-BB8254216032}"
\\PC9018\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="SWD\\MMDEVAPI\\{0.0.0.00000000}.{985F2B5C-2EE2-4733-BBD6-48BFDE2D5582}"
\\PC9018\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="SWD\\MMDEVAPI\\{0.0.1.00000000}.{71D824EA-DAE9-4F0D-B673-4425385E3777}"
\\PC9018\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="SWD\\MMDEVAPI\\{0.0.0.00000000}.{D29C0970-D515-4F91-9924-F0063CF1A196}"
\\PC9018\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="SWD\\MMDEVAPI\\{0.0.1.00000000}.{C4B331E2-C56B-4D9B-A486-2ED6C11FDB8C}"
```

**The problem**

My big problem now is, how do I associate the correct headsets microphone and earphone into a `Headset` object?

**The attempts**

I have tried searching Google and StackOverflow for an answer or hints, but I cannot find any common ground or relationship between the microphone and earphone using `WMI` or `MMDevice API`.

If there is a way to create a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the `Key` is something unique to the physical device or USB port, and the `Value` is a list of associated `Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID`, then I cannot find it.

In the spirit of *Star Wars Day* in a few days: "*Help me, StackOverflow. You are my only hope.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I have found the answer myself, with the help of [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) and Windows Registry. The code in the question is still correct, but NAudio makes it a bit easier.

I found the key to my problem inside Windows Registry under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render
```

Every device has a property called `{b3f8fa53-0004-438e-9003-51a46e139bfc},2` with a value similar to this `{1}.USB\VID_047F&PID_0416&MI_00\7&21995D75&0&0000`.

This looks to be a unique hardware ID, and is shared by the headset microphone and earphone (the same as the `Children` property from the question).

**The solution**

An interface with a single method to locate and return a list of headsets.

```
public interface IHeadsetLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Locate all connected audio devices based on the given state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceState"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IReadOnlyCollection<Headset> LocateConnectedAudioDevices(DeviceState deviceState = DeviceState.Active);
}
```

And the complete implementation. The real magic happens with the help of the `GetHardwareToken` method.

```
public class HeadsetLocator : IHeadsetLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Locate all connected audio devices based on the given state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceState"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Headset> LocateConnectedAudioDevices(DeviceState deviceState = DeviceState.Active)
    {
        var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        var relatedAudioDevices = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<MMDevice>>();
        var headsets = new List<Headset>();

        // Locate all connected audio devices.
        foreach (var device in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, deviceState))
        {
            // Gets the DataFlow and DeviceID from the connected audio device.
            var index = device.ID.LastIndexOf('.');
            var dataFlow = device.ID.Substring(0, index).Contains("0.0.0") ? DataFlow.Render : DataFlow.Capture;
            var deviceId = device.ID.Substring(index + 1);

            // Gets the unique hardware token.
            var hardwareToken = GetHardwareToken(dataFlow, deviceId);

            var audioDevice = relatedAudioDevices.GetOrAdd(hardwareToken, o => new List<MMDevice>());
            audioDevice.Add(device);
        }

        // Combines the related devices into a headset object.
        foreach (var devicePair in relatedAudioDevices)
        {
            var capture = devicePair.Value.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID.Contains("0.0.1"));
            var render = devicePair.Value.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID.Contains("0.0.0"));

            if (capture != null && render != null)
            {
                headsets.Add(new Headset("Headset", render.DeviceFriendlyName, capture, render));
            }
        }

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Headset>(headsets);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the token of the USB device.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataFlow"></param>
    /// <param name="audioDeviceId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetHardwareToken(DataFlow dataFlow, string audioDeviceId)
    {
        using (var registryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
        {
            var captureKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\" + dataFlow + @"\" + audioDeviceId + @"\Properties");
            if (captureKey != null)
            {
                return captureKey.GetValue("{b3f8fa53-0004-438e-9003-51a46e139bfc},2") as string;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help others in a similar situation.

*Happy coding*.